# How to format CSS in a readable way?

Tags: css

I’ve been trying to find out various ways to manage my CSS files which become bigger and bigger as time progresses. This has a few reasons: creating websites using responsive design, plugins that require additional styling or just page-specific styling for a single element.

There are a few techniques I’m already using, like:

- Creating a table of contents
- Separating code into named sections (to be referred in the table of contents)
- Name-spacing the elements (`.home-gallery`, `.home-gallery-image`, `.home-gallery-link` etc.)

Yet there’s still the issue of **how to lay down the properties for each element**.

Putting everything in a single line significantly decreases the readability. On the other hand, putting each and every property in a single line makes my scrollbar go sit under a shower and cry.

I’m currently experimenting with some different forms, and here’s what I came up with:

- Sorting and organizing properties according to their types
- Using tabulation/spacing to create a sort of table-look (captions on the left: elements; contents on the right: properties)

In an example it looks as follows:

```css
#content-wrapper {
                    position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
                    width: 100%; height: 200px;
                    color: #333; background: #fff;
                 }
```

For now it seems to me, like the only compromise between having to scroll endlessly/searching for a piece of code and making it less-readable.

So my question is: **What CSS writing techniques do you use that allow for good readability and further development?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general guidelines of writing code. I believe it's more appropriate if it were migrated to Programming.SE. Voted to close and flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** I define style in the order of elements in the HTML
eg: html{ }  head{ } body{ } likewise in the order. So while scrolling it will be easy to locate an element for me.

**2)** Writing styles in the order of screen width, if media query is included. From higher screen width to lower one. Which helps me to find the styles written for media elements easily. There also I follow the first point.

**3)** Format styles. It is almost like you did.

**4)** Keeping a documentation.

Comment: Concerning 2 - Isn't it actually the opposite? From smallest to biggest?

Comment: Every time my first concern goes to desktop, that is why I follow that. Once desktop styles are cleared, I moves to next width. Everybody needs the website to be clean and tidy in desktop first, that is what I think.

Comment: Here's an interesting look at the issue: http://designshack.net/articles/css/mobilefirst/

Comment: But this approach always worked for me and it never created trouble. I will refer to the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

sample below:

```
/* indented multi-selectors */
  #content-wrapper
, #content-wrapper > something else {
      /* alphabetic listing of properties, organizing attributes in blocks */

      background-color:    #fff;
      border-left-width:   2px;  /* column layout with blockwise different positioning */

      /* separation of blocks */
      color:    #333;
      height:   200px;
      left:     0;
      position: relative;
      top:      0;
      width:    100%;
  }
```

probably more important than formatting and organization of individual properties is a clean structure based on conspiring classes and proper documentation, especially of the rules' sequencing (it certainly has been in my projects. often the other way round ... ;-).

imho a decent folding editor sufficiently mitigates the need of frequent scrolling. and large screens, of course.